# script should point to the symlink

Tags: shell, scripting, symlink

I have a shell script which is used to deploy packages in udeploy I want to add my symlink to that shell i.e when the process is starting to run in udeploy my script should first refer the symlink and then according the environment it should get executed

Answer (score 0):

This question is quite unclear. what exactly you want do?

Maybe you wanna use `ln -s SOURCE TARGET` create symlink. or use `readlink -f LINK` to check the source of a symlink in shell